# How to correctly set repeated fields from json file

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

I have such `json` file:

```
[{
    "datafiles": ["data.data"]
}]
```

Description in `.proto` file:

```
message Dataset {
  repeated string datafiles = 1;
}
```

When I create a `Dataset` (`Dataset(datafiles=datafiles)`) object datafiles sets up in strange manner:

```
datafiles: "d"\ndatafiles: "a"\ndatafiles: "t"\ndatafiles: "a"\ndatafiles: ."\ndatafiles: "d"\ndatafiles: "a"\ndatafiles: "t"\ndatafiles: "a"
```

How to set it in correct way:

```
datafiles: "data.data"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your string (`"data.data"`) is being iterated and added one character at a time.

This suggests that you are probably passing in a string by itself:

```
"data.data"
```

when you should really be passing in an iterable containing strings:

```
[ "data.data" ]
```

Try printing the value of `datafiles` right before your call to create the `Dataset`:

```
print(repr(datafiles))

... whatever ... Dataset(datafiles=datafiles)
```